# Module not found error for django app to heroku when library and package name differs (works locally)

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to upload my updated django app to heroku - it works in my local system, but when I push my changes, it tells me it can't find a particular module (phonenumber_field).

This seems to be the case only when library and package names differ. For instance, when I install phonenumber_field, I use the command `pip install django-phonenumber-field`, while in the settings file, it is `phonenumber_field`.

I have ran `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, and the module in question is `django-phonenumber-field==2.0.0`. I have no idea where I'm going wrong, and wondering if someone could shed some light for me.

I don't think this is a case of the error in the following link as I had the same problem with bootstrap 3 until I used a CDN for bootstrap (bootstrap3 in the settings page but django-bootstrap3==9.1.0 in requirements.tx). https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-c-deps

ERROR MESSAGE

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Found python-3.6.3, removing
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.4
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 11.8.2…
remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (af8c37)…
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
remote:            app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
remote:            module = import_module(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'phonenumber_field'
```

REQUIREMENTS.TXT

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
Babel==2.5.3
certifi==2018.1.18
cffi==1.11.4
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.1.4
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==2.0.2
django-bootstrap3==9.1.0
django-phonenumber-field==2.0.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
nexmo==2.0.0
phonenumberslite==8.9.0
pycparser==2.18
PyJWT==1.5.3
pytz==2018.3
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
whitenoise==3.3.1
```

Comment: You seem to have a Pipenv file as well - can you post that?

Comment: It looks like you might be hitting [this issue](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field/issues/200)

Comment: Yes this seems to be it - I downgraded to Python 3.6.3, and for some reason, it seems to work.

Comment: "when I install phonenumber_field, I use the command pip install `django-phonenumber-field`, while in the settings file, it is `phonenumber_field`"—That shouldn't matter.

Comment: Note that if you're using `pipenv` (with `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`) you probably don't want or need a `requirements.txt` file. Use one or the other.